# The difference between pipelining and transaction in redis

Tags: transactions, redis

I am learning `redis`.
When I see the topic about `transaction` and `pipelining`, I feel uncertain.

When I use the `transaction`, client send some commands to the server one time，but when I use the `pipelining` I also send some commands to the server one time too.

What's the difference between pipelining and transaction?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pipelining vs transaction in redis](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29327544/pipelining-vs-transaction-in-redis)

Comment: thank you for much