# Atomically Execute commands across Redis Data Structures

Tags: go, redis, go-redis

I want to execute some redis commands atomically (HDel, SADD, HSet etc). I see the Watch feature in the go-redis to implement transactions , however since I am not going to modify the value of a key i.e use SET,GET etc , does it make sense to use Watch to execute it as transaction or just wrapping the commands in a TxPipeline would be good enough?

Approach 1 : Using Watch

```
func sampleTransaction() error{
    transactionFunc := func(tx *redis.Tx) error {
        // Get the current value or zero.

        _, err := tx.TxPipelined(context.Background(), func(pipe redis.Pipeliner) error {
            _, Err := tx.SAdd(context.Background(), "redis-set-key", "value1").Result()
            if Err != nil {
                return Err
            }

            _, deleteErr := tx.HDel(context.Background(), "redis-hash-key", "value1").Result()
            if deleteErr != nil {
                return deleteErr
            }
            return nil
        })
        return err
    }

retries:=10
    // Retry if the key has been changed.
    for i := 0; i < retries; i++ {
        fmt.Println("tries", i)
        err := redisClient.Watch(context.Background(), transactionFunc())
        if err == nil {
            // Success.
            return nil
        }
        if err == redis.TxFailedErr {
            continue
        }
        return err
    }
}
```

Approach 2: Just wrapping in TxPipelined

```
func sampleTransaction() error {
 _, err:= tx.TxPipelined(context.Background(), func(pipe redis.Pipeliner) error {
            _, Err := tx.SAdd(context.Background(), "redis-set-key", "value1").Result()
            if Err != nil {
                return Err
            }

            _, deleteErr := tx.HDel(context.Background(), "redis-hash-key", "value1").Result()
            if deleteErr != nil {
                return deleteErr
            }
            return nil
        })
return err
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, pipelines do not guarantee atomicity. If you need atomicity, use lua.
https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/mediocregopher/radix.v3#NewEvalScript

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29327544/pipelining-vs-transaction-in-redis